# Not Redirect some URL coming from a mobile

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect the url coming from a MOBILE and having the following url  format `www.mywebsite.com`  to `www.mywebsite.mobi.com`,

However, the URL with the following format `www.mywebsite.com/name/` (such as name is a string [a-z]+, this address will allow a user to access in her page) I do not want to redirect this type of url (`www.mywebsite.com/name/`). So when I write www.mywebsite.com/name/ in MOBILE, I want my web browser display the contents of the page `www.mywebsite.com/name/`

At this moment in my (.htacces) arrrive to redirect all urls to www.mywebsite.mobi.com. To accomplish this, I use the following code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) www.mywebsite.mobi.com [R,L]
```

How can I consider the two constraints in my code?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I happen to come across this: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ Just fill in your URL's and press one of the blue buttons to get the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add another `RewriteCond` into your directives, like this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/name/?$
```

And you can even change the `RewriteRule` therein into this rule if you want:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mywebsite.mobi.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Now if you want the name of the folder changed dynamically, check this condition as not as exact condition above:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
```

Comment: if (url==www.mywebsite.com) then 
 -apply redirection to www.mywebsite.mobi.com
else 
   if (url=www.mywebsite.com/name/) then 
     -does not apply redirection 
Endif
word name changes depending on the user. So, we will write it as a regular expression?

Comment: Do you mean the word `name` in the `/name/` of the folder is a variable that dynamically change? Example, `www.mywebsite.com/name1/`, `www.mywebsite.com/name2/`, `www.mywebsite.com/name3/` or `www.mywebsite.com/anything/` will not be redirected?

Comment: the word name changes dynamically Example, www.mywebsite.com/toufik/, www.mywebsite.com/servant/, www.mywebsite.com/name3/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `PHP`.

Just create a `PHP` file `Mobile_Detect.php` with the following code :

```
class Mobile_Detect {

protected $accept;
protected $userAgent;

protected $isMobile     = false;
protected $isAndroid    = null;
protected $isBlackberry = null;
protected $isOpera      = null;
protected $isPalm       = null;
protected $isWindows    = null;
protected $isGeneric    = null;

protected $devices = array(
    "android"       => "android",
    "blackberry"    => "blackberry",
    "iphone"        => "(iphone|ipod)",
    "opera"         => "opera mini",
    "palm"          => "(avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|palm|plucker|xiino)",
    "windows"       => "windows ce; (iemobile|ppc|smartphone)",
    "generic"       => "(kindle|mobile|mmp|midp|o2|pda|pocket|psp|symbian|smartphone|treo|up.browser|up.link|vodafone|wap)"
);


public function __construct() {
    $this->userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $this->accept    = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE'])|| isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])) {
        $this->isMobile = true;
    } elseif (strpos($this->accept,'text/vnd.wap.wml') > 0 || strpos($this->accept,'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) {
        $this->isMobile = true;
    } else {
        foreach ($this->devices as $device => $regexp) {
            if ($this->isDevice($device)) {
                $this->isMobile = true;
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Overloads isAndroid() | isBlackberry() | isOpera() | isPalm() | isWindows() | isGeneric() through isDevice()
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param array $arguments
 * @return bool
 */
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    $device = substr($name, 2);
    if ($name == "is" . ucfirst($device)) {
        return $this->isDevice($device);
    } else {
        trigger_error("Method $name not defined", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}


/**
 * Returns true if any type of mobile device detected, including special ones
 * @return bool
 */
public function isMobile() {
    return $this->isMobile;
}


protected function isDevice($device) {
    $var    = "is" . ucfirst($device);
    $return = $this->$var === null ? (bool) preg_match("/" . $this->devices[$device] . "/i", $this->userAgent) : $this->$var;

    if ($device != 'generic' && $return == true) {
        $this->isGeneric = false;
    }

    return $return;
}
}
```

And then write below line of code on the file which you are including on every page to redirect to mobile site from all pages.

```
include('Mobile_Detect.php');
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($detect->isMobile()) 
{
    // it is mobile platform
    header("Location:http://www.mywebsite.mobi.com");
}
```